# "If it is to happen" meaning

Tags: meaning

> If it is to happen then we should be ready for that

Here I am confused about the meaning of the sentence.

Does it mean "If it will happen" or something else?

Comment: Note that "if it will happen" is not idiomatic in English: we don't normally use the "will" future within an "if" or "when" clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If it is to happen**  [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/certain-or-likely-to-happen)

> likely to happen or be true, but not certain

As in:

> “Improvement, *if it is to happen* will occur where faculty and staff 
>   have the most leverage to change how they approach teaching and 
>   learning.”

[Ewell, Paulson, and Kinzie, 2011](https://studylib.net/doc/15500611/%E2%80%9Cimprovement%E2%80%94if-it-is-to-happen%E2%80%94will-occur-where-faculty-...)